# Call a material ui dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

How to call a Material UI `Dialog` during `onClick` on delete icon ie `onClick={deletePlayer(id)}` ?

I have added the *Dialog.js* under `modal/Dialog` and imported to *Home* component.

I have added a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-ellis-2h3pd?file=/src/components/Home.js)

Comment: Maintain a state to show the dialog. Set the state on click event

Comment: created a state  `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);` and inside the click event   `const deletePlayer = id => e => {
    alert("Delete this player data ! ");
    setOpen({ show: true });
  };`

Comment: You should call `setOpen(true)` in deletePlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [Forked CodeSandbox with working dialog](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-edison-zifyw)

Long answer:

First of all, you need to move the display/dismiss logic out of the `AlertDialog` component and into the component that actually triggers the display of the modal (in your case, the `Home` component). This means that you'll receive the `open` state and `onClose` handler as props (along with the `playerId` which will hold the ID of the player being targeted for deletion). So the signature of your dialog component becomes:

```js
export default function AlertDialog({ open, onClose, playerId }) {
  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose} ...> ... </Dialog>
  );
}
```

In `Home`, we add the logic to track and set the state of both the dialog open/closed status, and the ID of the player targeted for deletion. We do this through `useState`:

```js
  const [deleteDialog, setDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
  const [playerId, setPlayerId] = useState("");
```

While you *could* have as many `AlertDialog` components as you have players by adding `<AlertDialog />` inside your player `map` loop, it is redundant as you'll only ever have **one** modal active (by definition). So all you have to do is place a single instance of `<AlertDialog />` in your `Home` component. A good convention is to place it before the closing encompassing tag:

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">
      .
      .
      .
      <AlertDialog
        open={deleteDialog}
        onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
        playerId={playerId}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Finally, we deal with the handler responsible for displaying the modal, in your case `deletePlayer`. We have two things to do there: set the player ID targeted for deletion through the `playerId` state variable, and display the modal through the `deleteDialog` state variable:

```js
  const deletePlayer = id => e => {
    setPlayerId(id);
    setDeleteDialog(true);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, can i ask one more question, If I need to call the server via axios,  `const res = await axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player/${id}');` should I implement that in `deletePlayer` or in Dialog.js ? as it should be trigged on Yes on Dialog ...is that correct.

Comment: There are two ways you can deal with this: either implement it directly in `Dialog` inside the 'Yes' button `onClick` handler, using the `playerId` that has been passed as a prop, or craft an `onDelete` handler with a signature like `const onDelete = id => () => {  axios.delete(...); setDeleteDialog(false); }`, pass it to the dialog as a prop curried with the targeted ID (`<AlertDialog onDelete={onDelete(playerId)} .../>`) and use it as a handler for your 'Yes' button (`<Button onClick={onDelete}>Yes</Button>`). With the latter, you might decide you do not need the `playerId` prop anymore.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `onDelete` handler described in the second approach should be located inside `Home` (since it is passed as a prop to your dialog component).

Answer (score 1):

Create a state in the `Home` component to handle the Dialog visibility, set the state on click and render the `AlertDialog` conditionally:

```
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);

...

const deletePlayer = id => e => {
  setOpenDialog(true);
};

...

return(
  ...

  {openDialog && (
    <AlertDialog isOpen={openDialog} setIsOpen={setOpenDialog} />
  )}
```

Then in the `AlertDialog` component:

```
export default function AlertDialog(props) {
  const { isOpen, setIsOpen } = props;

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
  ...
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit interesting-rain-ed09o]